# How can I iterate the first element of each tuple in a list of tuples through a class method?

Tags: python, list, class, tuples

I am trying to determine if the first element meets a condition with an if statement, and if it does the next two items of the tuple will be inputted into the class method. so for example:

`x = [(345, 1000, 5),(576, 1345, 8), (234, 1175, 3)]`

In this instance I want to run the first element of the tuple, and if it means the condition, have the next two numbers be placed in the class method.

So far I have attempted to iterate by:

```
[i[0] for i in x]:
         if self.i >= 300 and self.i <=750:
              self.test1=[y[1] for y in x]
```

I have learned this cannot be done, and I cannot seem to get around this issue.

After the condition is met the other two elements are supposed to be aggregated into two variable so I can take the average.

```
def regional_stats(self):

        [zipcode[0]for zipcode in all_data]:
            if self.zipcode >= 10000 and self.zipcode <= 14999:
                self.NY_sqft = [sqft[1] for sqft in all_data]
                self.NY_avgsqft = statistics.mean(square_footage)
                return self.NY_avg_sqft
```

I am working with housing data and need the zip codes to stay together with the square footage and bedrooms hence why I cannot simply extract them separately as their own variables. I am trying to aggregate the square footage and number of bedrooms if they are within this range of zip codes

Comment: Can you show your desired output

Comment: I just added it above for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, here is the basic syntax that should get you where you need to be.

In this case I just printed the average of the tuple that meets the conditions, however you can replace the print() with anything that suits you.

```
import numpy as np
x = [(345, 1000, 5),(576, 1345, 8), (234, 1175, 3)]

for t in x:
    if t[0] >= 300 and t[0] <= 750:
        print(np.mean(t))
```

Output

```
450.0
643.0
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, as I am on the newer side of Python there are some technicals I am missing  that make my question confusing. I will give this a go with my program, thank you